# RadioButton Not Unchecking

Tags: android, radio-button

I know this has been asked a lot but I'm still quite unable to find a workaround for this one. These radio buttons are not clearing when I select another radio button. I don't want them to return or display a value but rather set the value.

All three radio buttons are inside the radio group with ID `radioGroup`

Please help. Thank you :)

```
public void onRadioButtonClicked(View view) {
    boolean checked = ((RadioButton) view).isChecked();

    switch(view.getId()) {
        case R.id.radioButton_plumber:
            if(checked) {
                internalWorkerType = "Plumbers";
                dbRef = db.getReference(Common.user_workers_table).child(internalWorkerType);
            }
            break;
        case R.id.radioButton_carpenter:
            if(checked) {
                internalWorkerType = "Carpenters";
                dbRef = db.getReference(Common.user_workers_table).child(internalWorkerType);
            }
            break;
        case R.id.radioButton_electrician:
            if(checked) {
                internalWorkerType = "Electricians";
                dbRef = db.getReference(Common.user_workers_table).child(internalWorkerType);
            }
            break;
    }
```

**XML Code**

```
<RadioGroup
    android:id="@+id/radioGroup"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textview_generic1">

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radioButton_plumber"
            android:layout_width="104dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:onClick="onRadioButtonClicked"
            android:text="Plumber"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/radioButton_carpenter"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="spread_inside"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radioButton_carpenter"
            android:layout_width="104dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:onClick="onRadioButtonClicked"
            android:text="Carpenter"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/radioButton_electrician"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/radioButton_plumber"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radioButton_electrician"
            android:layout_width="104dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:onClick="onRadioButtonClicked"
            android:text="Electrician"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/radioButton_carpenter"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

</RadioGroup>
```

[image]

Comment: What do you mean *"...radio buttons not clearing..."*? You mean not removing selection?

Comment: @Dumbo yes, it's supposed to select only one radio button within the group, not select all that you selected and that's what's happening with my codes.

Comment: Are you sure they are in the same radio group ? can you provide the xml code ?

Comment: It won't happen. Are you sure its under the Radiogroup?

Comment: @B.M updated the post

Comment: @ShaluTD yes please see updated post

Comment: RadioButton must be direct childs to RadioGroup, remove the constraintLayout and it will work

Comment: @B.M oh wow, it worked! Didn't knew it can't have a layout in between. Thank youuuuuu!!! :)

Comment: Happy to help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`RadioButtons` must be direct childs to `RadioGroup`, remove the `constraintLayout` and it will work

Answer (score 1):

Try by keeping the `ConstraintLayout` outside.

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
<RadioGroup
    android:id="@+id/radioGroup"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
   >


        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radioButton_plumber"
            android:layout_width="104dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:onClick="onRadioButtonClicked"
            android:text="Plumber"

             />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radioButton_carpenter"
            android:layout_width="104dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:onClick="onRadioButtonClicked"
            android:text="Carpenter"
             />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radioButton_electrician"
            android:layout_width="104dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:onClick="onRadioButtonClicked"
            android:text="Electrician"
           />
</RadioGroup>

  </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you'd like to use `ConstraintLayout` to manage `RadioButton` widgets layout, please visit https://github.com/samlu/ConstraintRadioGroup

The `blRadioGroup` widget can help to manage the changes of checked RadioButton in a `ConstraintLayout`.